# Unable to read ReturnUrl query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implemented my login page and it works fine, but I cannot read from the `ReturnUrl` query string parameter that holds the original requested URL.

For example, when successfully logging in from this page:

```
http://whatever/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fmenu-link.aspx
```

I get the following:

```
Context.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] = null 
Context.Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] = null
Context.Request.Url.ToString() = "http://localhost/Login.aspx"
UrlReferrer = "http://localhost/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Admin/menu-link.aspx"
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks for the answers but I don't use Session State on this particular website so it is not an option for me. The first time the user is redirected to the login page (after accessing a restricted page), I can correctly see the query string in the page_load, however it gets lost on postback.

Here is my page code, I don't know why it isn't persisting:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="Login.aspx" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnLogin">
    //Bunch of html
    <asp:Button TabIndex="5" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Log In" onclick="btnLogin_Click" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Where in the lifecycle are you reading the `QueryString`? Looking at your get the full URL as the referrer, I'd suggest you're trying to read it in the page after the login?

Comment: I am reading it in a button event on the login page. It is on the same page I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am reading it in a button event on the login page. It is on the same
>   page I don't know why this is happening

Your `form` is not preserving the `querystring` when the login button is submitted, as such it appears in the UrlReferrer.

Save the querystring to a session variable or append the query string to the `form` `action` attribute.

Comment: I got it to work by simply removing the `action` attribute from the form. Asp.net automatically inserted the correct one at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you were trying to get the `ReturnUrl` after you've logged in? Try the following in your `button_click`. It should just work. Your referrer shows you've made another request losing the querystring part without capturing it

```
string ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
Response.Redirect(ReturnUrl);
```

If you care, show the code in your `button_click`

Comment: I am getting it after I logged in, correct, but I am still on the same page. Sessions state is out of the question please see my edit above.

Comment: You should get it before postback occurs. If you postback to the same page the query string would go unless you capture it and append again.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the QueryString Parameter on Page_Load Event & save it in

```
ViewState["ReturnUrl"] = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
```

Then, in button click event do the redirection on authentication:

```
Response.Redirect(ViewState["ReturnUrl"].ToString());
```